# Django text file upload and security when using 'mark_safe'

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm working on a Django app where the user uploads a space/tab/comma delimited text file. I display the text in a browser and the user can then interactively parse columns of delimited values which get highlighted with css as they change the settings. (Only a sample is displayed not the whole file!)

To highlight the selections I insert html/css code in and around the text but have to 'mark_safe' the text to get the html/css to render. I assume this opens security issues as even I, a complete noob could insert html in my input file and get it to render.

My Question:
Is there something I can use to strip html out of the text file immediately after I've uploaded it and before I render it in the browser? Would stripping '<' and '>' out be enough? What about something to disable .js if required?

I understand there are other well documented security measures I can take regarding file uploads. However I'm after a solution to my specific issue relating to me 'marking_safe' the input text I then render to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django already has [Automatic HTML escaping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping) for this. Take a look at the link I posted in the docs. Hope this helps.

Comment: My point was that I'm effectively turning off autoescape by using 'mark_safe'. However the docs you linked to state that autoescape changes the    < > ' " &    characters only. I guess this is exactly the info I was after and I can manually apply to the input file, so thanks for the link!

Comment: from django.utils.html import escape. text = escape(text)